# SonarQube/SonarWeb - Can it scan dynamic HTML generated from a page?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I want to check if SonarQube provides capability to scan HTML generated from web pages through SonarWeb or any other plugin?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube is meant to analyse source code, not dynamically generated code.

So if you want to analyse a web site, this is not the tool you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this helps.